# IBM Sterling Configurator integration with Websphere commerce

Tags: tomcat, websphere, ibm-rad

I have installed Websphere Commerce 7.0 with feature Pack 4., SSFS9.1 and Visual Modeler9.1.

I Have followed the step mentioned in the IBM Info center link.
When i login to Managemnt Center and Navigate to Catalog Tool-->Store--> Catalog-->Category
and open dynamic kit.
I am able to launch Visual Modeler and add Model. 
But i am not able to view the Products from Management Center to Visual Modeler.
It gives me below error

Any pointer can help me in this

com.comergent.api.msgService.MsgServiceException: Error posting the message to URL
    at com.comergent.msgService.FormPostMsgServiceImpl.postRequest(FormPostMsgServiceImpl.java:71)
    at com.comergent.msgService.MsgServiceImpl.service(MsgServiceImpl.java:66)
    at com.comergent.appservices.appServiceUtils.OFApiHelper.invokeAPI(OFApiHelper.java:91)
    at com.comergent.apps.visualModeler.util.GetProductCategoryAndProduct.getProductCategoryAndProduct(GetProductCategoryAndProduct.java:70)
    at com.comergent.reference.appservices.productService.controller.EPOFProductCategory.getChildren(EPOFProductCategory.java:36)
    at com.comergent.reference.appservices.productService.controller.TVOFProductCategory.getTopLevelEntities(TVOFProductCategory.java:49)
    at com.comergent.reference.appservices.productService.controller.EntityPickerHierarchyViewController.processHierarchyView(EntityPickerHierarchyViewController.java:76)
    at com.comergent.reference.appservices.productService.controller.EntityPickerHierarchyViewController.execute(EntityPickerHierarchyViewController.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.DispatchServlet.executeController(DispatchServlet.java:485)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.DispatchServlet.doExecute(DispatchServlet.java:434)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.DispatchServlet.execute(DispatchServlet.java:340)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.DispatchServlet.dispatch(DispatchServlet.java:189)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.DispatchServlet.doGet(DispatchServlet.java:145)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:690)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.apps.mktAnalytics.identification.CookieCredentialFilter.executeFilter(CookieCredentialFilter.java:93)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.CredentialPropagationFilter.executeFilter(CredentialPropagationFilter.java:57)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.AAFilter.executeFilter(AAFilter.java:54)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.WrappingFilter.executeFilter(WrappingFilter.java:157)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.StatsFilter.executeFilter(StatsFilter.java:38)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.SSLSessionKeyFilter.handleHttpRequest(SSLSessionKeyFilter.java:79)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.SSLSessionKeyFilter.doFilter(SSLSessionKeyFilter.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.IPSessionTrackingFilter.doFilter(IPSessionTrackingFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.filter.csrf.CSRFFilter.validSecondarySessionIdReceived(CSRFFilter.java:253)
    at com.comergent.filter.csrf.CSRFFilter.doHttpServletFilter(CSRFFilter.java:89)
    at com.comergent.filter.csrf.AbstractServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractServletFilter.java:83)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.RequestControlFilter.executeFilter(RequestControlFilter.java:102)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.TimingFilter.executeFilter(TimingFilter.java:46)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:50)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.EntryFilter.executeFilter(EntryFilter.java:102)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.ComergentFilter.doFilter(ComergentFilter.java:58)
    at com.comergent.dcm.core.filters.EntryFilter.doFilter(EntryFilter.java:75)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:175)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:433)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:286)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:583)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:352)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:128)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:339)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:123)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:147)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:108)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:415)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:641)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:576)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:554)
    at com.comergent.api.msgService.LocalPost.postEntityReturnStream(LocalPost.java:336)
    at com.comergent.api.msgService.LocalPost.postEntityReturnReader(LocalPost.java:325)
    at com.comergent.api.msgService.LocalPost.postStringReader(LocalPost.java:178)
    at com.comergent.api.msgService.LocalPost.postString(LocalPost.java:156)
    at com.comergent.msgService.FormPostMsgServiceImpl.postRequest(FormPostMsgServiceImpl.java:68)
    ... 80 more

Answer (score 4):

I think you need at first to integrate the Sterling Selling and fulfillment with the Webshpere commerce in order to start using visual modeler and see your changes reflected on the IBM WCS check this Link

ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/commerce/doc/ssfs/92/SterlingOM92_InstallConfigWithWebSphereCommerce.pdf

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things, did you turn on Sterling Configurator in the Store in Management Center? Also, make sure you have the transport settings correct in Accelerator for your store or entire site.